# working with stack and pointers in c

Tags: c, stack

I'm working on pretty simple functions in c to manipulate the stack. Everything works fine, but I want to know how can I create a createstack() function, that sets pointer(s) to create an empty stack. And how can I use this function or structure in my push and pop functions.
Here's my code:

```
typedef struct nodeRec
{
    int item;
    struct nodeRec* next;
} node;
typedef node* nodePtr;
nodePtr top;


int isempty(nodePtr mytop)
{
    return mytop == NULL;
}

void push(int value1, nodePtr* mytop)
{
    struct nodeRec *newNode;
    newNode = (struct nodeRec*)malloc(sizeof(struct nodeRec));
    newNode->item = value1;
    if (isempty(mytop))
        newNode->next = NULL;
    else
        newNode->next = mytop;
    top = newNode;
    printf("\nElement added!!!\n");
    count++;
}
void pop(nodePtr* mytop)
{
    if (isempty(mytop))
        printf("\nStack is Empty!!!\n");
else {
    struct nodeRec *temp = mytop;
    printf("\nDeleted element: %d", temp->item);
    top= temp->next;
    free(temp);
    count--;
}
```

}

Comment: There are a few problems with your code. For example `nodePtr* mytop` is of type `node**` but you treat it as `node*`.

Comment: This is a good example of why making type aliases of pointers is a bad idea. Please don't do that, it invites mistakes such as yours. And besides, your compiler should have told you all about those problems, probably quite clearly.

Comment: Ok. I should leave out the nodePtr* mytop out and replace mytop with top. That works just fine. But my compiler didn't say anything and these functions work

Comment: With the stack design you're using, you never need a `createStack` function. `nodePtr stack = NULL; push(value, &stack);` and `pop(&stack);` work fine. Also, what you're doing wrong is stuff like `newNode->next = mytop;` (should be `*mytop`). Similarly, you need to use `isempty(*mytop)` in `push` and `pop`.

Comment: The functions "work" because you use the global variable `top` instead of the local variable `mytop`. I suggest you stop using global variables, and do some research about *emulating pass by reference in C*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
typedef struct {
    node *head;
    size_t size;
} stack_t;

size_t stack_size(stack_t *stack) {
    return stack->size;
}

bool is_empty(stack_t *stack) {
    return stack_size(stack) == 0;
}

stack_t *stack_create(void) {
    stack_t *stack = malloc(sizeof(stack_t));
    stack->size = 0;
    stack->head = NULL;
    return stack;
}

void push(stack_t *stack, int data) {
    node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct nodeRec));
    new_node->item = data;
    new_node->next = stack->head;
    stack->head = new_node;
    stack->size++;
}

int pop(stack_t *stack) {
    assert(!is_empty(stack));
    node *old_head = stack->head;
    stack->head = stack->head->next;
    int ret = old_head->item;
    free(old_head);
    stack->size--;
    return ret;
}
```

Of course, this isn't a super robust implementation, as it ignores some cases such as when invalid arguments (such as NULL pointers) are passed into stack interface functions, and error cases such as when `malloc` fails, but hopefully this is a good start.

The basic idea is that we define a type `stack_t` that stores all of the metadata that you're currently storing in global variables. Then, our `stack_create` function just needs to allocate memory for and initialize one of these `stack_t` types, and we can return a pointer to that. This way, you can easily have multiple stacks, each with their own `stack_t` header that can be passed into all of the stack interface functions.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -2):

Your example is a stack backed by a linked list. So in that case, you only need to maintain a pointer to the head;

```
struct stack {
   node *head;
};
```

On each operation, update `head` as needed.

```
void stack_push(stack *s, int val) {
    node *node = (node *) malloc(sizeof(node));
    node->item = val;
    node->next = s->head;
    s->head = node;
}
```

**EDIT**

@Osiris asks in the comments:

> node *stack would work fine, or not?

The reason this is a bad idea is because of pointer aliasing:

```
/* Declare the stack using Osiris' type */
node *stack1 = ...;
node *stack2 = stack1;

stack_pop(&stack1);
stack_push(&stack2, 0);  /* Crash accessing freed memory */
```

Obviously these references could be numerous and spread out across different modules. There's no way to guarantee the absence of pointer aliasing. You'd have no way of knowing if your `node *` was valid at any given time. That's why representing the stack simply as `node *` as suggested doesn't work.

Using a struct however, there is no possibility that operations performed through one reference can conflict with operations on another reference:

```
stack *stack1 = ...;
stack *stack2 = stack1;

stack_pop(stack1);
stack_push(stack2, 0); /* No crash */
```